# Break out of loop while calling function in python

Tags: python, function, asynchronous

I have a function called `evaluate` and it is a function that takes time to complete. It then resumes a loop, skipping that iteration:

My code:

```
array = []#some huge array containing different ways of expressing greetings

def main(resumeLocation):
    for a in range(len(array)):
        i = array[a]
        if a < resumeLocation:
            continue
        else:
            if (i == "Hello")
                answer(i, a)
                break

def answer(input, resumeLocation):
    # process answer
    resumeLoop(resumeLocation)
```

now, in order for the function not to loop infinitely, I need to skip the iteration where I process the answer, so I need to break the loop, call that function, then resume the loop, however, I cannot seem to work out how to do this.

any suggestions are helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to break from the loop?

Comment: because, if I don't then that function will be called and an infinite loop will happen

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the comments have mentioned, I believe there are better ways to do this, but if you really want to start a loop back where you broke out of it, you can try this approach:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

def answer(x, y, arr):
  print('About to restart the loop at index: ', x+1)
  loop(x+1, arr)

def loop(i, arr):
  for x in range(i, len(arr)):
    t = arr[x]
    print(t)
    if t == 3:
      answer(x, t, arr)
      break

loop(0, arr)
```

When the condition is met, `answer()` is called and the loop is broken, however the current index is preserved, and then when `answer` completes, the function is called with the correct starting index.  The output of this code is as follows:

```
1
2
3
About to restart the loop at index:  3
4
5
```

It correctly restarts the loop at the next index.